# Проблема с появлением неожиданных отступов в меню

Tags: html, css, меню

Есть блок с навигацией, в которой появляются непонятные отступы и возникает проблемы с вертикальным выравниванием меню. К примеру `.call-full` по высоте *120px*, а `.primary-navigation` *116px*. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/tcoso5f8/)
Понимаю, что это как-то связано с вхождением блоков `block` и `inline-block`, но как это решить?

```css
.call-full {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.primary-navigation {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-left: -99em;
  margin-right: -99em;
  padding-left: 99em;
  padding-right: 99em;
}

.main-navigation {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.main-navigation ul.menu,
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
  max-height: none;
  overflow: visible;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.618em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div classs="call-full">
  <div class="primary-navigation">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Основное меню">
      <div class="primary-navigation">
        <ul id="menu-menyu-v-shapke" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current_page_parent menu-item-241"><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-242"><a href="#about_us">О нас</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-243"><a href="#advantages">Преимущества</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-244"><a href="#reviews">Отзывы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вам просто надо убрать свойство `display:inline-block;` из класса `.primary-navigation` и вместо него поставить свойство `overflow: hidden;` . После этого высота будет ровно у всех `116px`